# SQL - Select multiple/all columns but exclude duplicate data in one or two specific columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Inspection) with the following columns

InspectionID (PK), ApartmentID (FK), HouseID (FK), InspectionDate

I want to retrieve a list of all houses and apartments that hasn't had an inspection in the last three months, and what the last InspectionDate was.

There can be no house or apartment showing up more than once, so I don't want any duplicates in either the ApartmentID or the HouseID.

```
SELECT ApartmentID, HouseID, InspectionDate
FROM Inspection
WHERE InspectionDate <= '2018-07-18';
```

This gives me everything I want, except of course that it shows duplicate values of houses and apartments, if they have had more than one inspection.

Comment: It is strange that you have two idea, `apartmentId` and `houseId`.  How are these used in your data?

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT ApartmentID, HouseID, MAX(InspectionDate)
FROM Inspection
GROUP BY ApartmentID, HouseID
HAVING MAX(InspectionDate) <= '2018-07-18';
```

This assumes that you want unique *pairs* of `ApartmentId` and `HouseId`.

The idea is to aggregate the data and using the `HAVING` clause to find those apartments/houses that have not been inspected since a given date.  If you want the query to have the date threshold based on the current date:

```
HAVING MAX(InspectionDate) <= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: This works perfectly, and such a simple and elegant solution too. Thanks a lot Gordon! To answer your question about the two separate ID's, there are two separate tables, one with houses that have certain attributes and the other with apartments that have a slightly different set of attributes.

Comment: Gordon's point is that if one of those columns is always null then a better model would be InspectionID, InspectionType(Apartment or House), ID.